# Why are my Datatable entries option, search box and page buttons disorganized?

Tags: html, database, bootstrap-4

I would like to know if someone could help me with a responsive Datatable that I have been creating for a website. I have been creating it with Bootstrap 4. I am going to show the code of the head of the website here, because I guess that the mistake is there, since the Datatable itself is fine, and only the search box, the pages buttons and the entries option are totally out of the place where they should be. So I would like some help specifically with those elements. Could you see if there are any problems with the:

- Search box
- Page buttons
- Options

If you see any other mistake in my "head" code and you would like to tell me about it, I would appreciate it. Thank you all.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cz">
    <head>
        <title> Semestrální projekt (měnit)</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.carousel').carousel({
                interval: 3000
                })
            });
        </script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tabulka').DataTable();
        } );
        </script>
        <script src="DataTables-1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="DataTables-1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="DataTables-1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styl2.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
```

Comment: Welcome. This seems to be a question about web applications in general and leaning toward more frontend. I would suggest edit your question to make it a clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I am answering my own question, since I have already solved it by myself, and I suppose it may help other people.*

The problem why the Datatable was not working (displaying) properly was really due to the "head" code that was formatted wrongly.

The code should be formatted like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cz">
    <head>
        <title>Semestrální projekt</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
            $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 3000
            })
            });
        </script>
        <script src="DataTables-1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
            $('#tabulka').DataTable();
            });
        </script>
        <script src="DataTables-1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="DataTables-1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styl.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
```

The mistake was simply that the version of the Bootstrap that was being using to create the responsive Datable was not specified in the code. If you look at the "head" code in the question, the Javascript and CSS files of the Datatable are included in it, but for a "general Bootstrap" (say it). Like this:

```html
<script src="DataTables-1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="DataTables-1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
```

While if you look at the "head" code here in the answer, the version of the Bootstrap that was being using is already specified, which was the Bootstrap 4. See the specific part of the code below:

```html
<script src="DataTables-1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="DataTables-1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" type="text/css">
```

In this case, this solved the problem. If you use the Bootstrap 4, and you have a similar problem, try this solution.

Besides that, in the "head" code in the question, there are two "jquery" files, which is not necessary. In the answer here, you may see that there is only one (the jquery 3.3.1), the javascript and CSS files of Bootstrap, and the javascript and CSS of the Datatable (specifying the version of the Bootstrap that was being used to create the Datatable, which is the version 4).